# Apple Magic Mouse on Ubuntu - slow scrolling

Tags: ubuntu, magic-mouse

I have an Apple Magic Mouse installed and working with Ubuntu 10.10 x86 on a Dell laptop.

The problem is that vertical scrolling is very slow in Gnome. A flick of the finger only scrolls a little bit. I want the fast hyperscroll action I get with this mouse on my Mac, or with the Revolution MX mouse I'm replacing...

Any fixes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me (on Ubuntu 11.04):

http://blog.matws.net/post/2010/10/16/Correct-magic-mouse-scrolling-on-Linux

Summary:

```
rmmod hid_magicmouse; modprobe hid_magicmouse scroll-speed=45 scroll-acceleration=1
```

Once you've adjusted the scroll speed and acceleration to your liking:

```
echo "options hid_magicmouse scroll-speed=45 scroll-acceleration=1" \
    > /etc/modprobe.d/magicmouse.conf
```

This improves the scroll speed and acceleration, but it does not scroll quite like it does on Mac. Specifically, it does not have the smooth inertia/momentum effect that causes the scrolling to "coast" to a stop when you flick your finger across the surface. Instead it jerks to a stop immediately when you lift your finger off the mouse.